# Basic Java - Packaging

Tags: java

I decided to post this question after trying to find an answer for it, and couldn't find one.
I'm studying for OCJP and tried few simple codes. This is what I did and need to do.

1. Created two .java sources, say *TestOne.java*, *TestTwo.java* [using
   notepad++]
2. Created a directory named "package1" and placed the two sources in
   them.
3. Both the source files have "package package1;" as their first statement.
4. *TestOne.java* has one public class and one class with default access.
5. *TestTwo.java* has one default class with an object of the default
   class in *TestOne.java*.
6. The main method is in this default class in *TestTwo.java*. It tries to invoke a method in 
   the referred object that was created, using *TestOne.java* default class.

So after all that was set up compiled *TestOne.java* then *TestTwo.java* by setting the flag "classpath" in javac [ javac -classpath  ]. Complied. But when I tried to run it gave me an exception "Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`". Does anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: how is this question related to android? Editing the tag

Comment: First tell me have you worked with android? then you should know that you need java to work with right? Hope that answer satisfies you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
javac -d path cname.java
```

so write the code like this

```
javac -d c:\main testone.java javac -d c:\main testtwo.java
```

`c:\main` should exist in your pc

then while executing

```
java -cp path pn.classname
```

so whichever class contains main (say test2)

```
java -cp c:\main package1.testtwo
```

Comment: Thanks "a dawg". It worked.

When compiling using javac need to add the -classpath because we are using a class in a package we had defined. This is something other than the general java packages.

javac -classpath "path" [ -d "path-of-generated-classfiles ] sourcename.java 
Once compiled and when we try to execute the the JVM couln't find the class file so thats why you have set the path using java commands "-cp" flag.

I didnt run it as "packagename.classfilename" just set "-cp" and then class name, thats what I was doing wrong.
Thanks again @a dawg @Nambi

Comment: yea glad to help..it was fussy when i was working on it..but eventually worked it out..

Answer (score 1):

run the code after compile

**compile** `javac TestTwo.java`

**run after compile**  `java TestTwo`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nambi... But java says classes with default access have access to other classes of the same package. import is necessary if the class is in another package. Am I right ?

Comment: yeah you are right..but you have the two class in different package right

Comment: No. Both .java files have "package package1;" declared at the beginning. That means both classes are in same package. Thats what I have in mind, is it wrong ?

Comment: Tried that also Nambi, still throws the exception. I tried everything that I possibly could think of and found out through googling still no progress. Thats why thought of posting here.